# Using Makefile as a script repository

Tags: scripting, make

Is it reasonable to use Makefile targets as scripts?

So for example, instead of having a script `script_A`, `script_B`, etc, and running them as standard executables with `./script_A`, we have a makefile that has targets `script_A`, `script_B`, and run them by invoker `make script_A`. There are no dependencies between the scripts.

In my eyes, this seems like an abuse of `make`. We're not using `make` to build programs, let alone for dependency management (i.e. topological sorting).

Comment: Reserver moral judgments for those things where they matter.

Answer (score 1):

This is not completely unusual, one could call it an idiom or pattern for `make`.

If you have certain build or processing steps for a project which somehow "belong together", and some of these steps just consist of running a script (maybe manually), then it makes sense to put the script calls simply as targets into the makefile, just as any other build target. This is a form of documentation, indicating that certain scripts belong to the project (and others, which are not part of the makefile targets, do not belong to it).

This only becomes an abuse if you start putting arbitrary, unrelated scripts into one makefile, just for the sake of making it possible to start them by typing `make script`.